# Monitoring method statistics

Tags: java, spring, monitoring, graphite, health-monitoring

I want to capture method execution statistics like method name, time taken by method etc in graphite.

We have 8 to 5 products and few of the products are legacy products which are not using spring. So what could be the best way to capture these statistics (in graphite) with very minimal change in the source code.

Comment: you mean profiling, for example using mission control?

Comment: not exactly profiling, i want to store the statistics in Graphite

Answer (score 1):

obviously to use an APM, and in my (opinionated view) the best tool for this is MoSKito:

http://www.moskito.org

If you don't want to change the source code at all: http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/monitoring-existing-application-using-moskito-javaagent/

If you are ok to change the source code slightly:
http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/

The last link is an example for spring, but it works with AOP annotations, so it should work with any tech you are using (even with ejb).

Last link: if you want to get a look on the tool itself, there is a video on you tube with a webinar held by the apache tomcat community:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RCkx-hGK1Q

Finally if you happen to live near Montreal, ApacheCon is in Montreal next week and there is a talk about MoSkito there:
https://apachecon.dukecon.org/acna/2018/#/scheduledEvent/0745118b5ee397ec3

best regards
Leon

Comment: Thanks @Leon, will try this

Comment: Does that send data to Graphite (which was the original question)?

Comment: @popieluch It doesn't have a direct graphite connector. People are using to send the data to graphite are either using collectd and collect the data via jmx beans or use moskito-central component, which can send the data to any (customizeable) storage

Answer (score 0):

Check [Dropwizard's Metrics library](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/)